# How to check exit if used tee?

Tags: linux, bash, command, exit

I try to use tee to save output in file like:

```
myapp | tee log.txt
```

But I have a problem with checking of exit. Previous code:

```
myapp 
if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
then .....
```

But $? will be exit of tee! Does it possible catch exit of myapp?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For bash, there's a convenient special array: PIPESTATUS. The return code for `myapp` would be in ${PIPESTATUS[0]} and so on.

zsh has a roughly identical method.

There's also a rather more annoying, hacky way to do it in strict bourne shells that you can read about in [the comp.unix.shell FAQ](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.unix.shell/msg/7a08dffe06316a29?hl=en).

Comment: +1. Read about `PIPESTATUS` in the [Advanced Bash Scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use [PIPESTATUS](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)

```
myapp | tee log.txt
if [ $PIPESTATUS[0] -eq 0 ] 
then .....
```

Answer (score -1):

you can redirect your output to file instead:

```
$ myapp > log.txt
```